# How to achieve load-balancing and failover between the two application servers through web server in WAS

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, ibmhttpserver

i am new in WAS so i configured WAS and also web server IHS then i created 2 application server

so through the web server the client can access the application then the traffic over HTTP to one of two application servers i created

integrate web server and 2 application server as an single endpoint then traffic distribute over applications server

[like thie img how can i do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzVW6.jpg)

so please can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install on IHS the [WebSphere Application Server plugin](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTJ_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.ihs.doc/ihs/tihs_install_config_twas.html). Then [generate the plugin config file](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/3-ways-generate-plugin-cfgxml). IHS will pass any http requests it cannot resolve to the plugin which will try to resolve to the known applications. If the plugin is not functioning properly then follow the instructions [here to collect data](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mustgather-websphere-application-server-http-plug-problems) and open an IBM Support ticket.